# Python JSON encoder convert NaNs to null instead

Tags: python, json, numpy, nan

I'm writing code to receive an arbitrary object (possibly nested) capable of being converted to JSON.

The default behavior for Python's builtin JSON encoder is to convert NaNs to `NaN`, e.g. `json.dumps(np.NaN)` results in `NaN`.  How can I change this `NaN` value to `null`?

I tried to [subclass `JSONEncoder` and override the `default()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) as follows:

```
from json import JSONEncoder, dumps
import numpy as np
    
class NanConverter(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        try:
            _ = iter(obj)
        except TypeError:
            if isinstance(obj, float) and np.isnan(obj):
                return "null"
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': np.nan, 'f': [1, np.nan, 3]}
>>> dumps(d, cls=NanConverter)
'{"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 2, "e": NaN, "f": [1, NaN, 3]}'
```

EXPECTED RESULT: `'{"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 2, "e": null, "f": [1, null, 3]}'`

Comment: Why don't you just replace the `NaN`s in the dictionary before you encode it?

Comment: I am receiving an arbitrary object capable of being converted to JSON and am not encoding it directly.  However, I want to ensure that NaNs are converted to null when I create the JSON string representation.

Comment: I'm thinking if that is a bug in the JSON encoder, because it produces invalid JSON. {"x": NaN} is syntactically incorrect JSON IMO. It should either output {"x": "NaN"} or {"x": null}. Both would be syntactically valid - which of those makes more sense is a different question.

Answer (score 48):

This seems to achieve my objective:

```
import simplejson


>>> simplejson.dumps(d, ignore_nan=True)
Out[3]: '{"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 2, "e": null, "f": [1, null, 3]}'
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this behavior in the built in json package? I'd rather not have another dependency on a third party package.

Comment: Not that I could find.

Comment: Doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 18):

1. As @Gerrat points out, your hook `dumps(d, cls=NanConverter)` unfortunately won't work.
2. @Alexander's `simplejson.dumps(d, ignore_nan=True)` works but introduces an additional dependency (`simplejson`).

If we introduce another dependency (pandas):

3. Another obvious solution would be `dumps(pd.DataFrame(d).fillna(None))`, but [Pandas issue 1972](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1972) notes that `d.fillna(None)` will have unpredictable behaviour:

   > Note that `fillna(None)` is equivalent to `fillna()`, which means the value parameter is unused. Instead, it uses the method parameter which is by default forward fill.
4. **So instead, use `DataFrame.where`:**

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(d)
   dumps(df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)))
   ```

Comment: `d` is a dictionary. It does not have the `where` method.  Even if it weren't, it appears that your method only returns non null values, whereas I want `null` in places where the value really is null.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected my solution to accomodate a dict.  Not sure about your other remark; I'll have to think about that.

Comment: This code doesn't work with OP's `d`. Even if you fix this snippet to use `d.items()` instead of `d`, and import `dumps` from `json`, the `nan` inside the list isn't converted.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame([0.5, np.nan])

df = df.astype(object)

print(df.where(pd.notnull(df), None))

Comment: `df.where(pd.notnull(df), None))` does not convert `nan`-values to `None` for numeric columns. One option is to convert all columns in question to the `object` datatype first with `df = df.astype(object)` as per @chris.au's comment.

Answer (score 15):

You can override the `encode` method of Python's `JSONEncoder` class, preprocessing `obj` and substituting `nan` to `None` (which will become `null` once serialized).

This seems to be the most straightforward way given that as *@Gerrat* noted the Python JSONEncoder will not call `default` when it encounters a `nan`. Even when calling `dump`/`dumps` with `allow_nan=False` it'll just throw an exception before giving the user the opportunity to "do their own thing".

```
import math
from json import JSONEncoder, dumps

def nan2None(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k:nan2None(v) for k,v in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [nan2None(v) for v in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, float) and math.isnan(obj):
        return None
    return obj

class NanConverter(JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().encode(nan2None(obj), *args, **kwargs)

>>> import numpy as np  # only needed as example also contains np.nan
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': math.nan, 'f': [1, np.nan, 3]}
>>> dumps(d, cls=NanConverter)
'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "e": null, "f": [1, null, 3]}'
```

Comment: I also had to check for a Decimal to have this work for my particular use case. It may be necessary to check other number types as well. 
`(isinstance(obj, float) or isinstance(obj, Decimal)) and math.isnan(obj)`

Comment: Great solution! _Note: since `JSONEncoder.iterencode()` is called from `JSONEncoder.encode()`, you don't really have to call `nan2None()` twice - it should be enough transforming the data in your `NanConverter.encode()`._

Comment: I think it could be validated as the correct answer. Overloading the encode method was also the right way for me, dIrectly without using another library.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, you probably need to use @Bramar's suggestion.  You're not going to be able to use this directly.  [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for Python's JSON encoder states:

> If specified, default is a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized

Your `NanConverter.default` method isn't even being called, since Python's JSON encoder already *knows* how to serialize `np.nan`.  Add some logging/print statements - you'll see your method isn't even being called.

Answer (score 7):

simplejson will do the right work here, but there's one extra flag worth including:

Try using simplejson:

```
pip install simplejson
```

Then in the code:

```
import simplejson

response = df.to_dict('records')
simplejson.dumps(response, ignore_nan=True,default=datetime.datetime.isoformat)
```

The ignore_nan flag will handle correctly all NaN --> null conversions

The default flag will **allow simplejson to parse your datetimes correctly**.

Comment: May I suggest you add the explanation about the `default` param as a comment to the accepted answer? Seems to make more sense than copying the accepted answer with one more param that is irrelevant to the OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

## Using Pandas

For those using Pandas, the simplest way - no third party libraries required: [df.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). This even converts NaNs and other Numpy types in nested stuctures:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'words': ['on', 'off'],
  'lists': [
    [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
    [[np.nan], [np.nan], [np.nan]],
  'dicts': [
    {'S': {'val': 'A'}},
    {'S': {'val': np.nan}},
  ]
})
```

If you convert it to a list of dicts, Pandas retains the native `nan` values:

```py
json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='record'))

> [{
    "words": "on",
    "lists": [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
    "dicts": {"S": {"val": "A"}}
  },
  {
    "words": "off",
    "lists": [[NaN], [NaN], [NaN]],
    "dicts": {"S": {"val": NaN}}
  }]
```

But if you have Pandas convert it straight to a JSON string, it'll sort that out for you:

```py
df.to_json(orient='records')

> [{
    "words": "on",
    "lists": [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]],
    "dicts": {"S":{"val":"A"}}
  },
  {
    "words": "off",
    "lists": [[null],[null],[null]],
    "dicts": {"S":{"val":null}}
  }]
```

Note that the `orient` value is slightly different between `to_dict()` and `to_json()`.

## Using Standard Library

If you're just working with lists and dicts and scalar values, you can convert NaNs manually:

```
import math

def to_none(val):
    if math.isnan(val):
        return None
    return val
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following workaround:

```
json_constant_map = {
    '-Infinity': float('-Infinity'),
    'Infinity': float('Infinity'),
    'NaN': None,
}

def json_nan_to_none(obj: typing.Any, *, default: typing.Callable = None) -> None:
    # We want to convert NaNs to None and we have to use for now this workaround.
    # We still want an exception for infinity and -infinity.
    # See: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13233
    json_string = json.dumps(obj, default=default)
    return json.loads(
        json_string,
        parse_constant=lambda constant: json_constant_map[constant],
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

The following example will replace nan with None

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> a = {"example": float("nan")} 
>>> a
{'example': nan}
>>> b = simplejson.dumps(a)
>>> b
'{"example": NaN}'
>>> c = simplejson.loads(b, parse_constant=lambda x: None)
>>> c
{'example': None}
```

Comment: Yes, @Mitar appears to have mentioned this sometime back.  It appears that this fix goes back to Python 2.7, so good find!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Pandas and want to serve JSON via Flask. It seems you can use `.replace` on a DataFrame to solve this relatively easily:

```
from numpy import nan as np_nan
...
@app.route('/json')
def json_endpoint():
  df = pd.DataFrame(...)
  df = df.replace(to_replace=np_nan, value=None)
  return df.to_dict()
```

Comment: I like `json.dumps(df.replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=None).to_dict())` as it is small, clear and without additional dependency (even if the dataframe is big it could be more expensive than a custom encoder)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to serialize the dictionary to a string, then replace "NaN" with "null", then encode it back:

```py
    d = json.dumps(d) # json dump string
    d = d.replace("NaN", "null")
    d = json.loads(d) # json load string
```

But you must be careful. If, for some reason, "NaN" is part of a string in some key or value inside the dictionary, this would require additinal care in the replace step.

Comment: Refer to the comment posted to Saurabh Chandra Patel's post.  Mainly that it is `null` not `"null"` (no quotation marks).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [orjson](https://github.com/ijl/orjson), [which is much faster than simplejson](https://github.com/ijl/orjson#latency).

```
>>> import orjson
>>> import numpy as np
>>> # orjson.dumps returns bytes, to match standard json.dumps we need to decode
>>> orjson.dumps(np.nan).decode()
'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13233) for this to be customizable in Python json standard library, but it is not yet merged in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I use for converting `NaN` to `None`. The nested **list**s also seem to be handled pretty well. The recursion of **dict**s is handled automatically.

```
def null_convert(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for i in obj:
            if isinstance(obj[i], float) and np.isnan(obj[i]):
                obj[i]= None
            if isinstance(obj[i], list):
                for j,v in enumerate(obj[i]):
                    if isinstance(v, float) and np.isnan(v):
                        obj[i][j] = None
    return obj

json.loads(json_str, object_hook = null_convert)
```

Answer (score 0):

@alexander Unfortunately, JSON does not support

> np.nan,
> np.NaN,
> np.inf,

It only support ***null***, refer this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp). But in Python, we have ***None*** option so null values can be replaced with ***None*** keyword

Other problems while converting dataframe or list in Python to JSON is, it won't support **numpy datatypes**, so we need to convert it to JSON acceptable data type, below is solution for the same

```
class CustomJSONizer(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
      if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
         return int(obj)
      if isinstance(obj, np.floating):
         return float(obj)
      if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
         return obj.tolist()
      if isinstance(obj, np.bool_):
         return super().encode(bool(obj))
      return super(CustomJSONizer, self).default(obj)
```

This is a custom class which takes care of various data type that you might come across while working with JSON file. To call this we need to use ***json.dumps***

```
with open('filename.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     f.write(json.dumps(Return_content,cls=CustomJSONizer, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simplest Solution

#### Recursive algorithm to Convert NaN to null

---

```
def transform(obj):
    """Function to check the data type to catch NaN and return the null value or return legitimate data type"""
    if isinstance(obj, float) and np.isnan(obj):
        return None
    if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
        return obj.tolist()
    if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
        return int(obj)
    if isinstance(obj, np.floating):
        return float(obj)
    return obj


def checking_object(obj):
    """ Take the dictionary element and recursively check inside
    the nested dictionary containing lists or lists containing Dictionary and converts NaN to null"""
    obj = transform(obj)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key in obj:
            if isinstance(obj[key], list) or isinstance(obj[key], dict):
                obj[key] = checking_object(obj[key])
            else:
                obj[key] = transform(obj[key])
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for idx, val in enumerate(obj):
            if isinstance(val, list) or isinstance(val, dict):
                obj[idx] = checking_object(val)
            else:
                obj[idx] = transform(val)
    return obj
```

---

You can pass the object to convert `NaN` to `null` here in the `checking_object` function.
`transformed_object = checking_object(json_having_NaN)`

---

### **No need for installing a third-party library like `simplejson`**

Answer (score 0):

as @rodrigo-silveira answered, using pandas pd.to_json() is a good way, with DataFrame as a bridge from dict to json. Here I add a code example to the example question code, hoping this would help someone who would see this answer:

```
import pandas as pd
from json import dumps, loads
import numpy as np

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': np.nan, 'f': [1, np.nan, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
json_result = dumps(loads(df.to_json())['0'])
print(json_result)

>>>{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "e": null, "f": [1, null, 3]}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use **simplejson** but if you want to use only JSON module then my trick

```
json.dumps(d).replace(", NaN," , ', "null",')
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `, null,` (unquoted)? Also, goes without mention, there are many possible ways in which the NaN could be found (with and without leading/railing comma, with/without spaces around it, as first or last element of an array, etc.