# pandas dataframe as nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a script that reads a nested JSON as a pandas dataframe and adds a new column to it and saves it back as JSON.

```
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

sample_json = {
    "name": {
        "emails": [{"address": "clark.kent@example.com"}],
        "countries": [{"country": "US"}, {"country": "UK"}],
    }
}
df = json_normalize(sample_json)

df["name.hobbies"] = np.nan

print(df)

df.to_json("sample.json", orient="records", lines=True)
```

My output looks like,

```
{
    "name.countries": [
        {
            "country": "US"
        },
        {
            "country": "UK"
        }
    ],
    "name.emails": [
        {
            "address": "clark.kent@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "name.hobbies": null
}
```

I would like to save the dataframe as nested JSON, like so,

```
"name": {
        "emails": [{"address": "clark.kent@example.com"}],
        "countries": [{"country": "US"}, {"country": "UK"}],
        "hobbies": null
    }
```

Is there a way to save a pandas dataframe derived from as a nested JSON?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion in nested json is simpliest create dictionary, add new value and last convert to json:

```
sample_json['name']['hobies'] = None

j = json.dumps(sample_json)
print (j)
{"name": {"emails": [{"address": "clark.kent@example.com"}], 
          "countries": [{"country": "US"}, {"country": "UK"}],
          "hobies": null}}
```

Pandas solution - create `MultiIndex` by split columns names and create nested dictionaries:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
d = {level: df.xs(level, axis=1).squeeze().to_dict() for level in df.columns.levels[0]}
print (d)

{'name': {'countries': [{'country': 'US'}, {'country': 'UK'}], 
          'emails': [{'address': 'clark.kent@example.com'}], 
          'hobbies': nan}}
```

And for convert `NaN`s to `null`s check [Python NaN JSON encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28639953), simpliest is set `None` instead `NaN`s or replace missing values by `None`s:

```
df = df.where(df.notna(), None)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
d = {level: df.xs(level, axis=1).squeeze().to_dict() for level in df.columns.levels[0]}

j = json.dumps(d)
print (j)
{"name": {"countries": [{"country": "US"}, {"country": "UK"}],
          "emails": [{"address": "clark.kent@example.com"}],
          "hobbies": null}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works well for two levels. I tried the same with 4 levels and it fails. 
For example, if my column names were like,

`'person.dob.date_range.start'`
`'person.dob.date_range.end'`
`'person.dob.display'`
`'person.educations'`
`'available_data.premium.dobs'`
`'available_data.premium.educations'`

Comment: @akileshraj - Working with nested json is pain, so try create this structure and I try find solution. But really not easy...