# Convert the dataframe to JSON Based on Column name

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains like this below, Am just providing one row !

```
Vessel_id,Org_id,Vessel_name,Good_Laden_Miles_Min,Good_Ballast_Miles_Min,Severe_Laden_Miles_Min,Severe_Ballast_Miles_Min


1,5,"ABC",10,15,25,35
```

I want to convert the dataframe to json in this format below,

```
{ 
   Vessel_id:1,
   Vessel_name:"ABC",
   Org_id:5,
   WeatherGood:{ 
      Good_Laden_Miles_Min:10,
      Good_Ballast_Miles_Min:15
   },
   weatherSevere:{ 
      Severe_Laden_Miles_Min:25,
      Severe_Ballast_Miles_Min:35
   }
}
```

how to join all those columns starting with good into a WeatherGood and convert to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert the dataframe to a dictionary of records, then transform each record to your desired format. Finally, convert the list of records to JSON.

```
import json

records = df.to_dict('records')
for record in records:
    record['WeatherGood'] = {
        k: record.pop(k) for k in ('Good_Laden_Miles_Min', 'Good_Ballast_Miles_Min')
    }
    record['WeatherSevere'] = {
        k: record.pop(k) for k in ('Severe_Laden_Miles_Min', 'Severe_Ballast_Miles_Min')
    }
>>> json.dumps(records)
'[{"Vessel_id": 1, "Org_id": 5, "Vessel_name": "ABC", "WeatherGood": {"Good_Laden_Miles_Min": 10, "Good_Ballast_Miles_Min": 15}, "WeatherSevere": {"Severe_Laden_Miles_Min": 25, "Severe_Ballast_Miles_Min": 35}}]'
```

Comment: In case, if Good_Laden_Miles_Min column contains NAN values , 
will that be a valid json ?

Comment: Refer to this post for NaN values with JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639953/python-nan-json-encoder Depending on your use case, you may also be able to convert the NaNs to a sentinel value.

Comment: So i can give like this json.dumps(records,ignore_nan=True) ???

Comment: After `import simplejson as json`

Comment: May I know why its getting shuffled like Vessel_id, Vessel_name coming next to next , But Org_id coming after WeatherSevere

Comment: Are you using Python 3.5 or earlier where dictionaries are unordered?  Order doesn't matter, although it makes the data more human readable.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 !! 
Out of curiosity for the order

Comment: Python 2.7 is no longer supported after the end of this month... https://pythonclock.org/