# How to replace Nan to None in json file via python?

Tags: python, json

Suppose here is a unknown json file.

```
data = json.loads(file)
```

It might looks like:

```
data = [
{"key1":"xxx","key2":"yyy","key3":"zzz"},
{"key1":"xxx","key2":Nan,"key3":"zzz"},
{"key1":"xxx","key2":"yyy","key3":Nan}
]
```

I want to change the value Nan to None.
What I did now is using a for loop and check every key's value. It looks stupid...
Are there a simple way to replace Nan to None? For example in pandas, we can use `df.replace` easily.

Comment: You *will* need to use a loop of some sort to do this, yes. Pandas also does the same thing, it just hides it behind one function call.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639953/python-json-encoder-convert-nans-to-null-instead

Comment: Check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467382/4985099